# ssh conection> Permission denied (publickey). Ubuntu 12.04 EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, key, rsa

I was using my EC2 instance 1 hour ago, I uploaded my web page using scp to my server and everything was fine. I closed the connection with exit command and now I am trying to log in using the same command as before and I'm getting this:

```
$ ssh -v -i /cygdrive/c/tsearch.pem ubuntu@tsearch.com.mx
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Connecting to tsearch.com.mx [54.201.232.244] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/tsearch.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/tsearch.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 3f:d4:cb:c0:db:7b:49:5e:0a:dc:1b:ec:4f:23:14:c3
debug1: Host 'tsearch.com.mx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Fernando/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/tsearch.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have searched over the web, and I have found different answers, but none has worked (and I dont want to delete my amazon instance). Any ideas?

Comment: Did you change anything in your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in your instance.  Or did you change anything on your private key on your Windows/Cygwin machine ?

Comment: No, anything. I just made a scp command and then all changed...

Comment: Where did you `scp` exactly into the instance. It's pretty possible that you overwrote the content of `~/.ssh`

Comment: Did you chmod 400 the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case to recover the data in the instance.  You can create an AMI from the instance, without rebooting. Then restart another instance using the AMI that you just created. Later, you can change your DNS (or Elastic IP) to point to your new instance.

[image: Create AMI]

Comment: Thank you so much, this was what i needed to do to fix this wierd problem